# Apply two matrices after one another in Manim

Tags: python, animation, matrix, manim

I am on Manim Community v0.17.2 and i am trying to animate linear Transformation A then wait a bit, and then animate linear Transformation B (I am not trying to animate the overall transformation A*B).

```
class LT(LinearTransformationScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            self,
            show_coordinates=True,
            leave_ghost_vectors=True,
        )

    def construct(self):
        A = [[1, 1], [1, -1]]
        self.apply_matrix(A)
        self.wait()

        B = [[2, 0], [0, 0.5]]
        self.apply_matrix(B)
        self.wait()
```

But this outputs the Error "All submobjects must be of type VMobject"

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```py
from manim import *


class LT(LinearTransformationScene):
    def construct(self):
        # Set up matrices
        A = [[1, 1], [1, -1]]
        B = [[2, 0], [0, 0.5]]

        # Animations
        self.apply_matrix(A)
        self.wait()
        self.moving_mobjects = []
        self.apply_inverse(A)
        self.moving_mobjects = []
        self.apply_matrix(B)
        self.wait()
```

We first apply the linear transformation `A`. Then we apply the inverse of `A` to reset the program, and then apply matrix `B`. Note that between every application of applying a matrix, you must put the line `self.moving_mobjects = []`. That is a known bug, but as of right now it is required to run the code properly.

If you don't want to animate the `self.apply_inverse(A)`, you can set the `kwarg` `run_time` to zero.

```py
from manim import *


class LT(LinearTransformationScene):
    def construct(self):
        # Set up matrices
        A = [[1, 1], [1, -1]]
        B = [[2, 0], [0, 0.5]]

        # Animations
        self.apply_matrix(A)
        self.wait()
        self.moving_mobjects = []
        self.apply_inverse(A, run_time=0)
        self.moving_mobjects = []
        self.apply_matrix(B)
        self.wait()
```

If this helped, consider upvoting and accepting this answer. If you have any questions, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the inverse? I just want to animate A then B.

Comment: @haifisch123 I don't think there is a way to do that (at least if there is, I could not find it). You could try setting the ```run_time``` kwarg to zero. I have updated my answer to include that.

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered reinstalling manim?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).